# Getting blank response from Linkedin

Tags: java, android, http, linkedin-api, codenameone

I am trying to request for user information after successful login in Codename one application, but when, after login user redirected to the application, But not getting any response.

**Following is my code:**

```
linked.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {


               Oauth2 auth2 = new Oauth2("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization", 
                "XXXXXXXXXX", 
                "https://www.codenameone.com","", 
                "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", 
                "XXXXXXXXXX");

       //auth2.authenticate();
        auth2.showAuthentication(new ActionListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                       AccessToken token = (AccessToken) evt.getSource();
                       JSONObject object = new JSONObject(token);
                       try {
                           TOKEN = object.getString("token");
                           Log.p(TOKEN);


                             ConnectionRequest linkedinreq = new ConnectionRequest(){
                   @Override
                   protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                      Log.p(input.toString());
                   }

             };
             linkedinreq.setPost(false);
             linkedinreq.setUrl("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-url)");
             linkedinreq.addArgumentNoEncoding("oauth2_access_token", TOKEN);
            linkedinreq.addArgumentNoEncoding("format", "json");
             NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(linkedinreq);


                       } catch (JSONException ex) {
                           ex.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               });
                Oauth2.setBackToParent(true);


       }
        });
```

**And the network monitor snapshot which display empty response**

[image]

**And the out put display in console**

```
[Network Thread] 0:0:1,12 - com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$67@41ca2b3e
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get any error message after override this message 
and call setreadResponseErrors(true); which will display error message and response code.

```
linkedinreq.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
     @Override
                protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
                    System.out.println("code: " + code + "message: " + message);
                }
```

Comment: I am working on Codename one application and when I am writing above code in my application it display CT error.

Comment: What was the response code of that response?  Also can you post the full content of the Response Headers from the screenshot?  (it was clipped at the top so is missing the first bunch).